# Regular expression to break out "Mon 15 December 2014 3:15 PM" in to date, hour, minute, am/pm

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in the format "Mon 15 December 2014 3:15 PM" which I want to break out in to:

- Date: "Mon 15 December 2014"
- Hour: "3"
- Minute: "15"
- AM/PM: "PM"

The issue is that some of them could be blank, so I could have " 3:15 PM", or "Mon 15 December 2014 :15 ", or " 3: " or just " : "

I know I could break this down in number of steps and separate it out but I'm wondering if there's a way in PHP to do this with a single (or at least fewer) regular expression.

Comment: Possible but not reasonable if you also want it to be valid. So what have you tried?

Comment: Does it really have to be done using regular expressions? It could be done using `strtotime()` and `date()`.

Comment: @TiborB. As I understand strtotime would only work if the string has a complete date. E.g. How could I extract the fields from " 3: "

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use regular expressions to achieve this. Here's a simple solution using `date()` and `strtotime()`:

```
$date_text = "Mon 15 December 2014 3:15 PM";
$date = explode("_", date("D d F Y_g_i_A", strtotime($date_text)));
print_r($date);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Mon 15 December 2014
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 15
    [3] => PM
)
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/q3us-tg6c

Alternatively, if you really want to use Regular Expressions, then here's another solution:

```
$pattern = '/((Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun)\s([\d]{1,2})\s(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)\s([\d]{4}))\s([\d]{1,2}):([\d]{1,2})\s(AM|PM)/';
$date_text = 'Mon 15 December 2014 3:15 PM';
$matches = array();
preg_match($pattern, $date_text, $matches);
echo "Date: " . $matches[1] . "<br />";
echo "Hour: " . $matches[6] . "<br />";
echo "Minute: " . $matches[7] . "<br />";
echo "AM/PM: " . $matches[8] . "<br />";
```

Outputs:

```
Date: Mon 15 December 2014
Hour: 3
Minute: 15
AM/PM: PM
```

PHPFiddle Link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gt94-dydb

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
$pattern = '~\A
    \s*+ (?=.) # prevent to match an "empty" string
    (?:(?<dayName>Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) \h+ )?
    (?:(?<day>\d{1,2}) \h+)?
    (?:(?<month>January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \h+)?
    (?:(?<year> \d{4}) \h+)?
    (?: (?<hour>\d{1,2})? : (?<minute>\d{1,2})? (?:\h+(?<ampm>[AP]M))? )?
    \s*
    \z
~xi';

if (preg_match($pattern, $strDate, $m)) {
    // depending of the matched fields, you can eventually complete them
    // and validate the date using strtotime.
}
```

Since all the fields are optional, I added the lookahead `(?=.)` preceded by `\s*+` to check if there is at least one non-whitespace character.

Feel free to improve the pattern to support, for example, short month names: `Jan(?:uary)?`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [date_parse_from_format](http://php.net/date_parse_from_format)?